# What to use for Custom Account Control in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership

I'm creating a custom authentication service (I just need more than the default allows).  I can't decide if I should extend [MembershipUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser(VS.100).aspx) and implement the appropriate interfaces, or completely roll my own.  Is there any advantaged to rolling my own, or any pitfalls I should be aware of when extending the default mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How far from defaults are you?

If your needs are far apart from what `MembershipProvider` gives you, I suggest you go with your own. I personally haven't come across an application that connected to an existing data store. So we would be adding another application to it. Hence I find `MembershipProvider` way over engineered. Authentication/Authorisation usually also doesn't take too much time to develop and you control it completely. If it does take a lot of time it's probably also far from what `MembershipProvider` gives you.

But if your requirements are close to `MembershipProvider`, then you should consider it. Either as it is or derive from it on your own. But beware. This may take more time than delivering your own, because you will have to learn it through and through.

### Security management requirements

If you go with MembershipProvider (or your own inherited class) you also get IIS integration so it's easy to manage security settings of your application. If you roll your own, you'll have to provide an interface for that as well which may take a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Honestly, I wish someone would roll a more lightweight open source option. I really can't stand ASP.net membership

Comment: @Matt Briggs: me neither. ANd saving XMLs in DB is just as stupid as it sounds. When you have DB to store data in, why handicap yourself?

Comment: here is an lightweight xml provider, if anyone is curious http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

Comment: That's what I thought. XML provider with XML files on disk, not saving them to DB. Actually the one by Mads is great.

Comment: I'm not even just talking about the provider, the whole damn API is far too complex for most cases. Not to mention that implementing your own provider is a royal pain. There are about 30 required methods, and anything else you need to do not covered by their API requires casting Membership.Providers["yourName"] to your Type to access. 

I don't want to plug into a crappy auth system. I either want something that plugs into MY api, giving me auth related stuff for free (like password hashing/salting/resetting/etc), or an out of box solution using code generation or partials to allow customizing

Comment: @Matt I know exactly what you mean.  I got really frustrated when I realized it would be near impossible to create a user with more than a password and e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Implement MembershipProvider abstract class. I have an implementation with XML as datastore right here, if you need it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx?queryresult=true

Answer (score 0):

Its always good fun to write your own provider but it depends on the security needs of the application you are building.

Most occasions when I have had to implement my own provider.

- Using an orm such as nhibernate.
- No database so requried to use flat xml files.
- I had to build a system that required a more extensive role-permission system than the membership classes provided.

Good thing is you can switch between different providers if you need too..